# Как поднять рамку выше?

Tags: html

Может кто сталкивался? Можно их как то рядом поставить?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
вот как оно выглядит:D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ссылка на страницу не помешала бы, но судя по всему у вас это блочные элементы, какими по-умолчанию являются теги `<div>` есть несколько вариантов на вскидку:

1. выставить этим блокам свойство css `float` ([jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/aLgu2ry0/1/))
2. обернуть в родительский элемент (если они на одном уровне с текстом) и этому родителю задать `display: flex`. Почитать доходчиво о flex [можно здесь](http://html5.by/blog/flexbox/) (пример [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/krgb7whh/2/), если будете копировать, не забудьте удалить комментарии из стилей)

Comment: _"Ссылка на страницу не помешала бы"_ - помешала бы. А вот [mcve] - нет.

Comment: На счет примера согласен, а вот на счет ссылки или хотя бы части кода  вы бы согласились со мной видя, что блоки, находясь на разных строках выровнялись то слева, то справа. То есть какая-то структура там уже есть и вероятно нужно дополнение к данным здесь ответам и рекомендациям

Comment: Пришлось немного изменить код. Но спасибо вам огрмное:) Вы мне помогли:)

Answer (score 1):

У вас на сайте подключен twitter bootstrap?

Если да то можете каждую из рамок поставить класс col-lg-6.

А если нет то дать стиль примерно так

```
.block{

   display: inline-block;

   width: 50%;

}
```

где block это класс вашего отдельного блока.

Comment: проблема в том, что как и у любого инлайнового элемента дальше придется решать проблему с отступами по краям, которые не дают разместить два таких элемента с шириной в 50% в одной строке - [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tc22knsm/1/)

Comment: Лучше всего подключить bootstrap, и сново не изобрести велосипед.

Comment: не нужно ради этого подключать bootstrap ;)